# JOptionPane dialog box for output of result

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am working on a school assignment where I am trying to calculate the tax bracket based off of what the user inputs into the GUI. I am trying to figure out how to add a text box at the end with the results, but so far I am only able to just do `out.println`.

```
import java.swing.JOptionPane;
public class GUI {    

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fn = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter house value");
        int house = Integer.parseInt(fn);

        double tax = 0;

        if (house <= 8500)
            tax = house * 0.10;
        else if (house <= 34500)
            tax = house * 0.15;
        else if (house <= 83600)
            tax = house * 0.25;
        else if (house <= 174400)
            tax = house * 0.28;
        else if (house <= 379150)
            tax = house * 0.33;
        else if (house >= 379150)
            tax = house * 0.35;

        if (house <=  8500)
            System.out.println("You have entered the 10% bracket. Due: $" + tax);
        else if (house <= 34500)
            System.out.println("You have entered the 15% bracket. Due: $"+ tax);
        else if (house <= 83600)
            System.out.println("You have entered the 25% bracket. Due: $"+ tax);
        else if (house <= 174400)
            System.out.println("You have entered the 28% bracket. Due: $"+ tax);
        else if (house <= 379150)
            System.out.println("You have entered the 33% bracket. Due: $"+ tax);
        else if (house >= 379150)
            System.out.println("You have entered the 35% bracket. Due: $"+ tax);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "text box"?

Comment: I mean a JOptionPane message that has the resulting value for the tax

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(..);`

Answer (score 0):

First off, does your assignment force you to do all of this with JOptionPanes? Judging purely from your Use-Case it seems a lot more logical to have a usual JDialog with an input textfield and an output textfield already incorporated into the UI.

Second, it makes no sense at all to use JOptionPane for your output. The name of the object already says it, JOptionPane, it is used when the user is supposed to choose between options. An output window does not offer any options, it's mere purpose is to output information to the user that shouldn't be interacted with.

Keeping that in mind, you're a lot better off using a JDialog for your output window. If you haven't noticed yet, your class right now throws a `NumberFormatException` on `parseInt(fn)` if you input any non-Integer values or even if you press the cancel option (because you are not checking what is input at all).

I'll use that little design flaw to make sure we have a usable value and thereby determine the initialization of the output window. This code won't be perfect or optimized, but it will do what you want it to.

```java
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fn = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter house value");
        int house = Integer.parseInt(fn);
        String taxBracket = "";
        
        try
        {
            double tax = 0;
            
            if(house <= 8500)
            {
                tax = house * 0.10;
                taxBracket = "10%";
            }
            else if(house <= 34500)
            {
                tax = house * 0.15;
                taxBracket = "15%";
            }
            else if(house <= 83600)
            {
                tax = house * 0.25;
                taxBracket = "25%";
            }
            else if(house <= 174400)
            {
                tax = house * 0.28;
                taxBracket = "28%";
            }
            else if(house <= 379150)
            {
                tax = house * 0.33;
                taxBracket = "33%";
            }
            else if(house >= 379150)
            {
                tax = house * 0.35;
                taxBracket = "35%";
            }
            
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
            dialog.setTitle("Output");
            
            JPanel outputPanel = new JPanel();
            String output = new String("You have entered the " + taxBracket + " bracket. Due: $" + tax);
            JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel(output);
            outputPanel.add(outputLabel);
            
            dialog.add(outputPanel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: The entered Input is non-numeric.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now again, if your assignment forces you to do this with 2 JOptionPanes, just replace the code initializing the JDialog with a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` and simply pass the output String to the JOptionPane.